# How to check Variant for null?

Tags: null, d, variant

I am getting answer from DB and need to check if it is not `null` before placing it's to value.

I tried few variants of checking, but my code is still crush:

```
foreach(i, point;myPointsLonLat)
{                   

    try
    {
        carGPSPoint cargpspoint;
        cargpspoint.id = point[0].coerce!ulong;

        cargpspoint.recordDate = DateTime.fromSimpleString(point[1].coerce!string).toISOExtString(); // some magic to get string in 2016-10-31T15:37:24 format
        if(point[2].hasValue) //check if we have some data
            cargpspoint.velocity = point[2].coerce!double;
        if(point[3].hasValue)
            cargpspoint.lat = point[3].coerce!double;
        if(point[4].hasValue)                   
            cargpspoint.lon = point[4].coerce!double;
        cargpspoints[i] = cargpspoint;
        b.next();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        writeln("\n----------------------------ERRRRRR-----------------------");
        writeln(point);
        writeln("1111: ", point[2].coerce!double);
        writeln("2222: ", point[3].coerce!double);
        writeln("3333: ", point[4].coerce!double);
        writeln(e.msg);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
----------------------------ERRRRRR-----------------------
Row([1478698195002489886, 2016-Nov-09 13:29:55, 153, null, null], [false, false, false, true, true])
1111: 153

object.Exception@C:\D\dmd2\windows\bin\..\..\src\phobos\std\variant.d(823): Type typeof(null) does not convert to double
```

As you see it's print `1111: 153`. But crashing on other null variables.

I also tried:

```
    if(point[2].type !is null) //check if we have some data
        cargpspoint.velocity = point[2].coerce!double;
    if(point[3].type !is null)
        cargpspoint.lat = point[3].coerce!double;
    if(point[4].type !is null)                  
        cargpspoint.lon = point[4].coerce!double;
```

Same result. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`hasValue` checks if it has been initialized, and the database library does initialize it, just to null.

I'd suggest checking the type directly:

```
 if(auto pt = point[3].peek!double)
                cargpspoint.lat = *pt;
```

`peek` checks if it has that exact type and returns a pointer to the value if it does. It is an *exact* match, meaning if it is `float` or something else, this won't work, so make sure you are matching what the database gives you (that's best for performance and accuracy anyway), but then it will be null and thus skip the `if` it isn't right and you can set if it is.

Just repeat that pattern for all your points.

Comment: It's look like a little bit hacky. How this problem is solving in another languages? Maybe I should mention about it in bug-tracker?

Comment: What is "hacky" about checking the actual data against your actual expectations?

Comment: I expect something like `.isNull` or some other methods. Or at last that `.hasValue` will return false on `null`. Is seems that it's done in such way in C#. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution to implement the `isNull` function and a `hasValue2` function in the way you wanted:

```
import std.variant;
import std.stdio;

void main()
{
    Variant v;
    writefln("%s %s %s", v.hasValue, !v.isNull, v.hasValue2);
    v = null;
    writefln("%s %s %s", v.hasValue, !v.isNull, v.hasValue2);
    v = "";
    writefln("%s %s %s", v.hasValue, !v.isNull, v.hasValue2);
}

@property bool isNull(Variant v)
{
    return v.type == typeid(typeof(null));
}

@property bool hasValue2(Variant v)
{
    return v.hasValue && !v.isNull;
}
```

Result:

```
false true false
true false false
true true true
```

So in your code you should check for `typeid(typeof(null))` instead. You might be right that `hasValue` should check for `typeof(null)` as well. IIRC `Variant` predates `typeof(null)`, nowadays it might even make sense to use only `typeof(null)` and never allow uninitialized `Variants`.

Please start a discussion at https://forum.dlang.org/group/general or file a bug report at https://issues.dlang.org to discuss this with the appropriate library maintainers.